# Only showing the first sentence of a WordPress post on the front page as a "highlighted post" section

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently working on my first WordPress theme and I want to create a "Highlighted Post" section on my index.php. There are a lot of scripts for this but all seem to apply a permanent filter over the entire index.php. That is problematic since i want to show the whole posts on my index.php below. Is there a way to apply this special filter only for this section and not for the whole index.php?

Comment: I would suggest you to use JavaScript/jQuery for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could give us more info what determines this "Highlighted" posts we might be able to be more specific in solving this.

But in the mean time I'll guess it's two latest posts which means you could have two queries in the index.php

First one would be for "Highlighted" ones:

```
<?php
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => 2 );
  $lastposts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
?> 

  <h2 class="news"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This will give you excerpt of your post in this query.

What you could do then is limit excerpt to whatever length you'd like and add read more link if you want :)

```
function newExcerpt($more) {
   global $post;
   return '... <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read more</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'newExcerptReadMore');


function customExcerptLength( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'customExcerptLength', 999 );
```

And for other posts you could do another query but not using first two posts like this:

```
$count = 0;
$lastposts = get_posts();
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
if($count > 1)
?> 

  <h2 class="news"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  $counter++;

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This will just loop through the posts and skip first two posts.
If you have some other term or category or something else that determine Highlighted posts then you can use that in and pass it as an argument to get_posts($args).

Comment: That's excactly what I wanted, thank you so much! Currently I got no time to test it out but in case of an error I'd prefer responding to this question again. :^)

Comment: No problem let me know how did it go :) And accept answer if that's good for you :)

Comment: Okay now I'am ready to test it out! :^) So about your second last post..Where do I have to position it? In the functions.php? But what about the third line of code then? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's working if i put the code above my content that needs to have this filter applied on, but im getting this warning and after a little research I still have no idea how to fix it:

Comment: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'newExcerptReadMore' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/web1205/html/floriangoetzrath-wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298

Comment: Ahh yeah `add_filter('excerpt_more', 'newExcerptReadMore');` should be `add_filter('excerpt_more', 'newExcerpt');` sorry about that...